# How Can I Use Django 3 with MongoDB?

Tags: django, mongodb

Is there a way that I can use Django 3 + MongoDB because djongo (the package which integrates MongoDB and Django) requires Django 2.x. Note that I don't want to move to Django 3 for specific reasons. I just wanna explore it. and I need MongoDB because I am writing a data analysis web app (since NoSQL Databases Perform well when working with large data sets). thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Mongoengine](http://docs.mongoengine.org/tutorial.html) and you don't need to run migration commands but Mongoengine do not support regular Django contrib libraries directly, so it would be more complicated to adjust it to Django regular libraries which means it’s hard to have admin and other Django regular libraries